# How to add counts to sankey diagram when axis categories differ?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add counts to my labels on a sankey plot, but I have been a bit stuck on how to proceed for some time

I have this data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Before = c("Poor", "Poor", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Normal",
             "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Normal",
             "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor",
             "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal",
             "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal",
             "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal",
             "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate",
             "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Intermediate",
             "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Intermediate",
             "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor"),
  After = c("Poor", "Poor", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal",
            "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal",
            "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate",
            "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor",
            "Normal", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate",
            "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor",
            "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate",
            "Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal",
            "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Poor", "Normal", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Poor",
            "Intermediate", "Normal", "Normal", "Poor", "Intermediate", "Normal", "Intermediate or Indeterminate", "Intermediate or Indeterminate","Intermediate or Indeterminate", "Intermediate or Indeterminate", "Poor", "Poor", "Normal", "Poor or Normal", "Poor or Normal", "Poor or Normal")
)
```

I make the plot like this:

```
transition_counts <-  data %>% make_long(Before, After)

# Create Sankey plot
ggplot(
  transition_counts,
  aes(
    x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node,
    next_node = next_node, fill = factor(node),
    label = node
  )
) +
  geom_sankey(
    flow.alpha = .6,
    node.color = "gray30"
  ) +
  geom_sankey_label(
    aes(x = as.numeric(x) + .05),
    size = 4 / .pt, color = "white", fill = "gray40",
    hjust = 0
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 4) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

Which gives this:

[image]

I try to gets counts for the before and after axis something like this:

```
before_counts <- transition_counts [!is.na(transition_counts $next_x),] %>% dplyr::group_by(node)%>% tally()
after_counts <- transition_counts [!is.na(transition_counts $next_x),] %>% dplyr::group_by(next_node)%>% tally()
```

I think I have to merge these back into the `transition_counts` and then pass `label=n` to the `ggplot` function instead of `label=node`, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this in a way that does not plot nonsense. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could achieve your desired result using `after_stat` which allows to access any values computed under the hood by the `geom` or `stat`. For the present use case, the counts are already computed by `geom_sankey(_label)` and stored internally in a variable or column named `freq`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsankey)

transition_counts <- data %>% make_long(Before, After)

# Create Sankey plot
ggplot(
  transition_counts,
  aes(
    x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node,
    next_node = next_node, fill = factor(node)
  )
) +
  geom_sankey(
    flow.alpha = .6,
    node.color = "gray30"
  ) +
  geom_sankey_label(
    aes(
      x = as.numeric(x) + .05,
      label = after_stat(paste0(node, "\nn = ", freq))
    ),
    size = 8 / .pt, color = "white", fill = "gray40",
    hjust = 0
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 4) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

[image]